# Get EntryID of new mail

Tags: vbscript, outlook

We made a script that automatically opens the Microsoft Outlook new mail window. Some things have to be filled in already. This works so far:

```
Set Arguments = WScript.Arguments
If Arguments.Count > 4 Then
    Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set BodyObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Mail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)

    Mail.To = Arguments(0)
    Mail.CC = Arguments(1)
    Mail.BCC = Arguments(2)
    Mail.Subject = Arguments(3)

    Set BodyFile = BodyObject.OpenTextFile(Arguments(4))
    Mail.Body = BodyFile.ReadAll
    BodyFile.Close

    For Counter = 5 to (Arguments.Count - 1)
        Mail.Attachments.Add Arguments(Counter)
    Next

    Mail.Display
End If
```

But know we want to know if that mail gets sent by the user and we also want to know the EntryID of that mail, so we can look it up later.

Now Mail.Display doesn't return anything and the program just ends. It does not wait until the window gets closed. So after Mail.Display, there should be something like: Mail.Wait, or a Mail send event so we can get the EntryID.

Could someone help us out?

Thanks in advance,
Gillis and Emiel

Comment: I have the same problem, except that I'm trying to achieve the same in VB.Net. I've tried to retrieve the EntryID from the Write event that occurs once the MailItem has been sent. Not much luck though. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a probable solution from [here](http://www.visualstudiodev.com/visual-studio-tools-for-office/entryid-on-send-async-delegate-44898.shtml):

> You need to wait and get the EntryID
>   value after the item has been
>   delivered from the Outbox. To do this,
>   subscribe to the Folder.Items.ItemAdd
>   event on the Sent Items folder. That
>   event passes the newly added -- i.e.
>   newly sent -- item as its argument.

Answer (score -1):

The item must exist first in Outlook to have an EntryID value, use the Save Property and fetch its EntryID right after

```
Mail.Save
strEntryID = Mail.EntryID
```

I've got a sample written in VBA for saving notes from Access form to Outlook

```
    Dim outobj As Outlook.Application
    Dim outappt As Outlook.NoteItem
    Set outobj = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    Set outappt = outobj.CreateItem(olNoteItem)
    With outappt
    If Not IsNull(Me!strBody) Then .Body = Me!strBody
    .Save
    Me!strEID = .EntryID
    End With
```